Spring WebFlux loading large amount of data without encountering OOM
I am new to Spring WebFlux, lately i have encountered OOM in a Spring WebFlux project.
Inside this project, there is only one scheduled job runs one time per day.
The job contains the following actions:
Scan all items from a dynamoDB table (there are 1 million items in this table and each item has 40kb)
Transform each item into a new Object
Upload these transformed objects into AWS S3 bucket as one single json file
After reviewing the dump file, the root cause is too many Map<String, AttributeValue> objects not being released. Because the amount of items from the table are too large so it keeps scanning items(and not releasing them i guess) and eventually the heap area is overloaded and throws OOM.
I have tried other approaches to process the data in chunk by using Mono.buffer() or by using AtomicInteger class to control the thread keeps scanning items. But none of them works.
My expectation is: can this job keeps processing items in chunk (e.g. 1000 at a time)? Like:
fetch 1000 items -> transform 1000 items -> multipart upload items -> end of chunk process -> start another fetch 1000 items ...
and make sure the memory release after the each sub-process
To reproduce:
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * ?")
    public void job() {
        Flux.range(0, 8)
                .flatMap((segment) -> scanningDB(segment, 8, null))
                .collectList()
                .subscribe();
    }

    private Flux<Map<String, AttributeValue>> scanningDB(Integer segment, int totalSegment, Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKey) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> {
                    ScanRequest scanRequest = ScanRequest.builder()
                            .segment(segment)
                            .totalSegments(totalSegment)
                            .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
                            .exclusiveStartKey(lastKey)
                            .build();
                    return Mono.fromFuture(dynamoClient.scan(scanRequest));
                })
                .map((scanResponse) -> {
                    transformAndUpload(scanResponse.items()).subscribe();
                    return scanResponse;
                })
                .filter(ScanResponse::hasLastEvaluatedKey)
                .flatMapMany((scanResponse) -> scanningDB(segment, totalSegment, scanResponse.lastEvaluatedKey()));
    }

    
    private Mono<Void> transformAndUpload(List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> items) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(items)
                .map(this::transformItems)
                .collectList()
                .flatMap(this::uploadToS3);
    }

I will skip the transform and S3Upload part as root cause is too much object(software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue) not being released

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

These are just pseudo code, anyway i will remove them, thanks for the advice :)

There are nio details. Add a [mre].

I have added the pseudo code example inside the context, appreciate!

I have found a similar case related to the topic: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27965
